# sqoop import - GSS initiate failed - Failed to find any Kerberos tgt

Tags: security, kerberos, cloudera, sqoop

sqoop import - errors out
sqoop list-tables/ eval works fine.

Distribution: Cloudera
Security issue:

> GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials
>   provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
>
> WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException
>   as:pars7611 (auth:KERBEROS) cause:java.io.IOException: Failed on local
>   exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS
>   initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided
>   (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)];   ERROR
>   tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: Failed on local
>   exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS
>   initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided
>   (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)];

Comment: Did you run a kinit before running sqoop command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

> GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials
>   provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]

is usually caused by no Kerberos ticket. Please use kinit to get a Kerberos ticket before running sqoop command.

That being said, it was puzzling that it can do list-tables, evals. The metastore should be protected by Kerberos authentication too. Please check whether the hive metastore is secured by Kerberos, that is, the `hive.metastore.sasl.enabled` is set to be true or not.